# How to display blog posts only from the administrator

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

my website is running on word-press v4.7 with the twenty 17 theme. its a multiple author blog so i want to display blog posts only from the administrator and leave out posts from other users.

i have tied enetering this code in the functions.php file but it didnt work

```
$users = get_users( array( 'who' => 'author' ) );


foreach ( $users as $user ) {   

    if($user->caps['Administrator']!=1) continue;     

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
                            'posts_per_page'=>1, 
                            'author' => $user->ID
                            ) 
                    );
    if($query->have_posts()):
        while($query->have_posts()):
            $query->the_post();
            get_template_part('content', 'postlist'); 
        endwhile;
    else:
        get_template_part('content', 'none'); 
    endif;
}
```

Comment: By default, the WordPress administrator ID is set to 1

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: cool thanks i will. but how do i solve this problem